# (symfony5 twig) Can't apply more than one inline css in emails

Tags: css, twig, symfony5

https://symfony.com/doc/current/mailer.html#using-external-css-files

I've gone trough this and it even says that "You can pass unlimited number of arguments to inline_css() to load multiple CSS files."

I have defined a namespace called "css".

```
twig:
    default_path: '%kernel.project_dir%/templates'
    form_themes: ["bootstrap_4_layout.html.twig"]
    paths: 
        "%kernel.project_dir%/public/css": css
        "%kernel.project_dir%/public/images": images
```

Despite this when I pass multiple css files it only loads the last one. If i swap positions it loads the bootstrap.min.css but not my custom css.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

{% apply inline_css(source("@css/bootstrap.min.css"), source("@css/style.css")) %}

<html>
    <body>

    </body>
</html>

{% endapply %}
```